# BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted in android 5.0 while trying AES incryption/decryption

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes

I am trying Encryption/Decryption in android using code provided 
here:
http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.com/2013/10/android-example-for-encrypt-and-decrypt.html

The code is working for my device which runs android 4.1 but does not seem to run in an android 5.0.1 device

The error Log is provided below.

AESHelper Class:

```
package com.myapplication;



import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;

    import java.security.SecureRandom;

    import javax.crypto.Cipher;
    import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
    import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
    import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class AESHelper {

public static String encrypt(String seed, String cleartext) throws Exception {
    byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
    byte[] result = encrypt(rawKey, cleartext.getBytes());
    return toHex(result);
}

public static String decrypt(String seed, String encrypted) throws Exception {
    byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
    byte[] enc = toByte(encrypted);
    byte[] result = decrypt(rawKey, enc);
    return new String(result);
}

private static byte[] getRawKey(byte[] seed) throws Exception {
    KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    sr.setSeed(seed);
    kgen.init(128, sr); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available
    SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
    byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();
    return raw;
}


private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);
    return encrypted;
}

private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
    return decrypted;
}

public static String toHex(String txt) {
    return toHex(txt.getBytes());
}
public static String fromHex(String hex) {
    return new String(toByte(hex));
}

public static byte[] toByte(String hexString) {
    int len = hexString.length()/2;
    byte[] result = new byte[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2*i, 2*i+2), 16).byteValue();
    return result;
}

public static String toHex(byte[] buf) {
    if (buf == null)
        return "";
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(2*buf.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
        appendHex(result, buf[i]);
    }
    return result.toString();
}
private final static String HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF";
private static void appendHex(StringBuffer sb, byte b) {
    sb.append(HEX.charAt((b>>4)&0x0f)).append(HEX.charAt(b&0x0f));
}


}
```

MainActivity Calss:

```
package com.myapplication;

 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;



 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String seedValue = "This Is MySecure";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String normalText = "ABCD";
    String normalTextEnc;
    try {
        normalTextEnc = AESHelper.encrypt(seedValue, normalText);
        String normalTextDec = AESHelper.decrypt(seedValue, normalTextEnc);
        TextView txe = new TextView(this);
        txe.setTextSize(14);
        txe.setText("Normal Text ::"+normalText +" \n Encrypted Value :: "+normalTextEnc +" \n Decrypted value :: "+normalTextDec);
        setContentView(txe);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e("MYAPP", "exception", e);
    }



}
```

Log:

```
07-02 21:06:45.545 11608-11608/com.myapplication E/MYAPP: exception
                                                                      javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted
                                                                          at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher.engineDoFinal(BaseBlockCipher.java:854)
                                                                          at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1340)
                                                                          at com.dhungana.aditya.myapplication.AESHelper.decrypt(AESHelper.java:54)
                                                                          at com.dhungana.aditya.myapplication.AESHelper.decrypt(AESHelper.java:27)
                                                                          at com.dhungana.aditya.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:948)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:743)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to declare a padding algorithm if your input is not a exact multiple of the key length.

Try to instantiate the cipher with "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"

Comment: i changed the **Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");**  to **Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");** but now its giving me **javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt**

Comment: Did you add it also to the encryption?

Comment: Yes I added it to both encryption and decryption.

Comment: @AD1TYA , how did you fix it?

Comment: Sadly, I haven't fixed it yet.